# iterate function over list, and append the returned values

Tags: python, function, counter, average

I have a CSV data set, 40 columns by 800 ish rows.
But as an example lets say its looks like this:

```
Ref  X  Y
11   1  10 
11   2  9
11   3  8
11   4  7
12   5  6 
12   6  5
12   7  4
13   8  3
13   9  2
```

How would you define a function that returns a list of the average X and Y values for each Ref? i.e to yield something like:

```
Ref_list = [11,12,13]        
Av_X = [2.5,6,12.5]
```

I doubt this is the best way to approach it, but I've written the following code:

```
my_data = genfromtxt('somedata.csv', delimiter=',',skiprows=1) 

X=[]
for i in my_data:
    X.append(i[0])
    counter=collections.Counter(X)
    keys=np.sort((counter.keys())) #find and sort ref key values

def getdata():
    X , Y = [], []
    for i in my_data:
       if i[0] == refs:
           X.append(i[1])
           Y.append(i[2])
    AV_X=np.average(X)
    AV_Y=np.average(X)
    return AV_X, AV_Y

for refs in keys: # run function over key range 
    AV_X, AV_Y = getdata()
```

here i get stuck, i was trying iterate the function over the range of ref no. (keys) and append the returned values. But other than errors, i can only get the values for the last Ref. in keys.

I imagine there is a better way to do this, but i'm still a newbie to this stuff.
Many thanks in advance for any suggestions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the brilliant [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/index.html) library for those kind of jobs:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO('your_data'),
        delim_whitespace=True)

df.groupby('Ref').mean()

       X    Y
Ref          
11   2.5  8.5
12   6.0  5.0
13   8.5  2.5
```

As you can see in the last row, you miscalculated in your question...

You can likewise ask for [median, sum, max, etc..](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/basics.html#descriptive-statistics)

Comment: also, you can cut the StringIO and replace it with the file path. `df = read_csv('test.csv',delim_whitespace=True)
df.groupby('Ref').mean()`

Comment: @root yes, correct, thanks ... initially I had the input from above in a string, but then I decided to skip those line for clarity

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> A=np.array([[11,1,10,],[11,2,9],[11,3,8],[11,4,7],[12,5,6,],[12,6,5],[12,7,4],[13,8,3],[13,9,2]])
>>> A
array([[11,  1, 10],
       [11,  2,  9],
       [11,  3,  8],
       [11,  4,  7],
       [12,  5,  6],
       [12,  6,  5],
       [12,  7,  4],
       [13,  8,  3],
       [13,  9,  2]])
#Slice the data
>>> A[:,0]
array([11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13])
>>> refs=np.unique(A[:,0])
#Unique value of all references.
>>> refs
array([11, 12, 13])
#To get the average of each column
>>> np.average(A,axis=0)
array([ 11.77777778,   5.        ,   6.        ])
```

I think you want this though?

```
#Create a mask
>>> A[:,0]==11
array([ True,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
>>> Mask=A[:,0]==11
>>> A[Mask]
array([[11,  1, 10],
       [11,  2,  9],
       [11,  3,  8],
       [11,  4,  7]])
>>> np.average(A[Mask],axis=0)
array([ 11. ,   2.5,   8.5])
>>> np.vstack([np.average(A[A[:,0]==x],axis=0) for x in ref])
array([[ 11. ,   2.5,   8.5],
       [ 12. ,   6. ,   5. ],
       [ 13. ,   8.5,   2.5]])
```

So in the end you can just have:

```
>>> refs=np.unique(A[:,0])
array([11, 12, 13])
>>> np.vstack([np.average(A[A[:,0]==x],axis=0) for x in ref])
array([[ 11. ,   2.5,   8.5],
       [ 12. ,   6. ,   5. ],
       [ 13. ,   8.5,   2.5]])
```

There is a better way to do it by introducing higher dimensional matrices so you can avoid list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv, collections, operator
def j(): return dict(X=[], Y=[])
def mean(inlist): return operator.truediv(sum(inlist),len(inlist))
a = collections.defaultdict(j)
# get all the data
for line in csv.DictReader(open(myfile, 'r')):
    a[line['Ref']]['X'].append(line['X'])
    a[line['Ref']]['Y'].append(line['Y'])


# now, for the averages themselves

def get_avgs(inputlist, xy):
    return [mean(a[item][xy]) for item in inputlist]
```

Use:

```
get_avgs([11,12,13], 'X')
# returns:
[2.5,6,12.5]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it all in one pass, without sorting first, if you wanted to.

```
counts = {}
averages = {}
for line in data_file:
    ref = line[0]
    data = map(float, line[1:])
    if ref not in counts:
        counts[ref] = 1
        averages[ref] = data
    else:
        counts[ref] += 1
        averages[ref] = map(lambda running, new: ((running * (counts[ref] - 1)) + new) / counts[ref], averages[ref], data)
```

You could use `defaultdict` for `counts` and `averages`, but I think that it doesn't really help with clarity or brevity enough in this case to warrant it.

It would probably be more efficient though if you did it in 2 passes, though still without sorting.

```
counts = {}
totals = {}
for line in data_file:
    ref = line[0]
    data = map(float, line[1:])
    if ref not in counts:
        counts[ref] = 1
        totals[ref] = data
    else:
        counts[ref] += 1
        totals[ref] = map(lambda running, new: running + new, averages[ref], data)
averages = {ref : map(lambda total: total / counts[ref], totals[ref]) for ref in counts}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't even bother with numpy for anything below a few hundred thousand rows... why not just use this:

```
#assuming your data is a list of lists and you want the average of the 2nd column
avg = sum(x[1] for x in mydata) / len(mydata)
```

Of course if you only want the average of all items matching some expression, use a list comprehension to filter the data and then calculate the average over the resulting list:

```
my_specific_data = [x[1] for x in mydata if x[0] == refs]
#... avg as above
```